# Why are viewHolders not garbage collected

Tags: android

I have an activity in which i replace fragments that act as each screen.

I open a fragment and press back (pops it from the backstack) and get back to the previous frag. Then, I press the "Initiate GC" button

[image]

and then I dump the Java heap and get the below things.

[image]

Seems that the fragment FMenuForm is not released form memory, right ? The only things that seem to still be in memory are the ViewHolders used in the RecyclerView ... but why ?!

I've set `this.my_recycler_view.setAdapter(null)` in the `onDestroy()` method of the fragment, but it still doesn't seem to want to gc it.

[image]

**EDIT**

Here's the code for the `Adapter` and `ViewHolders`. They're both inner classes to `FMenuForm`

```
public class FMenuForm extends Fragment{


private RecyclerView list_view;

private AdapterMenuForm mAdapter;

private int mIndexSelected = 0;

//
// PRIVATE IMPLEMENTATION
//

private ListItemClickCallback.OnListItemClickListener<AdapterMenuForm.ListItem> mItemClickCallback =
        new ListItemClickCallback.OnListItemClickListener<AdapterMenuForm.ListItem>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onListItemClicked(View view, AdapterMenuForm.ListItem item, int position) {
                //TODO:
            }
        };

/** Some other method and fields here  */    


//
// ADAPTERS
//

private class AdapterMenuForm extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RowHolder> {

    private final int TYPE_SUBCATEGORY = 0;
    private final int TYPE_THEME = 1;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private ArrayList<ListItem> mSubcategories;

    //
    // CONSTRUCTOR
    //

    public AdapterMenuForm() {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    }

    //
    // ADAPTER
    //


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSubcategories == null ? 0 : mSubcategories.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mSubcategories.get(position).isSubcategory() ? TYPE_SUBCATEGORY : TYPE_THEME;
    }

    @Override
    public RowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int type) {
        if (type == TYPE_SUBCATEGORY) {
            return new RowHolderSubcategory(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_form_menu_parent, viewGroup, false));
        } else {
            return new RowHolderTheme(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_form_menu_child, viewGroup, false));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RowHolder holder, int position) {

        ListItem data = mSubcategories.get(position);

        //Label
        holder.text.setText(
                data.isSubcategory()
                        ? data.item.subcategory.name
                        : data.item.theme.name);

        //Highlight
        holder.itemView.setActivated(mIndexSelected == position);

        //Check icon
        //TODO:
        holder.icon.setActivated(position % 2 == 0);

        //Arrow
        holder.arrow.setVisibility(
                data.children.size() == 0 ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE
        );
        holder.arrow.setImageResource(
                data.isExpanded ? R.drawable.selector_expandable_icon_up : R.drawable.selector_expandable_icon_down
        );

        //Click listeners
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new ListItemClickCallback<ListItem>(mItemClickCallback, data, position));
        holder.arrow.setOnClickListener(new ListItemClickCallback<ListItem>(mArrowClickCallback, data, position));


    }

    //
    // PUBLIC IMPLEMENTATION
    //

    public void setData(final FormOptionsListItem items) {

        /** Long method. Nothing interesting. Populated mSubcategories*/

    }

    //
    // CLASSES
    //

    private class ListItem {

        boolean isExpanded = false;

        FormOptionItem item;

        ArrayList<ListItem> children = new ArrayList<>();

        public ListItem(FormOptionItem item) {
            this.item = item;
        }

        public boolean isSubcategory() {
            return item.remote_theme_id.contentEquals("0");
        }

        public boolean isTheme() {
            return !item.remote_theme_id.contentEquals("0");
        }

    }

}

public static class RowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView text;
    private View icon;
    private ImageView arrow;

    public RowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_form_menu_text);
        this.icon = view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_form_check_icon);
        this.arrow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_form_check_icon_arrow);
    }
}

public static class RowHolderSubcategory extends RowHolder {
    public RowHolderSubcategory(View view) {
        super(view);
    }
}

public static class RowHolderTheme extends RowHolder {
    public RowHolderTheme(View view) {
        super(view);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Which part would you be interested in exactly ?

Comment: Adapter and holder

Comment: @AndreiBogdan most interested is your part with viewholder implementation =)

Comment: Done. Hope it's enough.

Comment: The `ListItem` objects don't seem to be gc as well :( Does it have to do anything that the adapter is an inner class (not static) ? I just thought of it ...

Comment: @AndreiBogdan, shouldnt class AdapterMenuForm be static aswell? In other case fragment and adapter will never be cleared by GC

Comment: Nope, same thing. 
The interesting thing I've just noticed is that if I press the "Initiate GC" one, it does gc a bunch of memory but not the viewholder and ListItem objects. If I press it again though, it does. ?!?! I'm very confused.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is you defined `AdapterMenuForm` inside a class, but it's not static. Follow the documentation from `EffectiveJava`, this is not legal.(`item22`)

> If you declare a member class that does not require access to an enclosing instance, always put the static modifier in its declaration , making it a static rather than a nonstatic member class. If you omit this modifier, each instance will have an extraneous reference to its enclosing instance. Storing this reference costs time and space, and can result in the enclosing instance being retained when it would otherwise be eligible for garbage collection ( Item 6 ). And should you ever need to allocate an instance without an enclosing instance, you'll be unable to do so, as nonstatic member class instances are required to have an enclosing instance.

The solution is, try to make your `Adapter` class be a nested static class or move it to another folder: `adapters`? Then create a `constructor` to init your `mSubCategories`.

Comment: well thats what I wrote in my comment. The problem is with ViewHolder classes which are static already.

Comment: No. Your viewholder is static class, but AdapterMenuForm class is not

Comment: AdapterMenuForm is the inner class of FMenuForm